# Nested Case is not working in doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

what i need

- i want to check that data of certain country should be on top .

here is my  query syntax

- problem in this syntax please point out my mistake.

  ```
    (case
           when user.linkedinProfile IS NOT NULL or user.country=$country_code
           then 1
           else
              case
                    when user.profile IS NOT NULL or user.country=$country_code
                    THEN 2
                    else
              end

              case
                      when user.country or user.country=$country_code
                      then 3
                      else 4
              end 
          END)as country
  ```
- Where i have done wrong (i have used case ->when->then ->else->end).

  but sql  query is working in database:

  ```
      SELECT e0_.metadata AS metadata0, u1_.id AS id1, u1_.linkedin_id AS linkedin_id2, u1_.facebook_id AS facebook_id3, u1_.linkedin_profile AS linkedin_profile4, u1_.profile AS  
      profile5,u1_.country,

    CASE WHEN u1_.linkedin_id <> '' OR u1_.facebook_id <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS sclr6, 
    CASE WHEN e0_.edition = 23932 THEN 'current' ELSE 'past' END AS sclr7 ,
            case
              when u1_.linkedin_profile!='' and u1_.country='IN'
              then '1' 
              when u1_.profile!='' and u1_.country='IN'
              then '2'
              when u1_.country and u1_.country='IN'
              then '3'
          else '4'
          END  lower 

        FROM event_visitor e0_, user u1_

      WHERE e0_.user = u1_.id AND e0_.event = 25162 AND e0_.published = 1 GROUP BY 
      e0_.user ORDER BY e0_.edition DESC, sclr6 DESC, e0_.id DESC , u1_.country DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
  ```
- i putting priority on query .
- i have taken help from [Nested CASE statements in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618730/nested-case-statements-in-mysql)

  like ex

  ```
    linkedln url (not null) and country ( 1 priority).
    profile (not null) and country (2 priority).
    country (not null) and country( 3 priority).
  ```

i have found the solution:

```
              (case
             when (user.linkedinProfile !='' or user.profile !='') and user.country= '$country_code'
              then 1
                when
                user.linkedinProfile<>'' or user.profile!=''
                then 2
                when  user.country='$country_code'
                then 3
            else 4 end)  country
```

Error :

```
         PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException' with message 'SELECT  user.country,visitor.metadata,user.id user_id,user.linkedinId,user.facebookId,user.linkedinProfile,user.profile,\n\t\t\t\t(case  when user.linkedinId !='' or user.facebookId !='' then 1 else 0 end) social,\n\t\t\t\t(case  when visitor.edition =23932 then 'current' else 'past' end) edition,\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tCASE\n\t\t\t\t     WHEN (user.linkedin_profile IS NOT NULL and user.country='IN' )\n\t\t\t\tTHEN \n\t\t\t\tCASE\n\t\t\t\t     WHEN(user.profile IS NOT NULL and user.country='IN')\n\t\t\t\tTHEN '2' \n\t\t\t        ELSE '3'    \n\t\t\t\tEND\n\t\t\t\tELSE\n\t\t\t\tCASE\n\t\t\t\t    WHEN (user.country and user.country='IN')\n\t\t\t\tTHEN '4'\n\t\t\t\tELSE '5'\n\t\t\t\tEND\n\t\t\t\tEND AS product_total\n\t\t\t\t    FROM Entities\\EventVisitor visitor,Entities\\User user WHERE visitor.user=user.id AND visitor.event=25162 AND visitor.published=1 GROUP BY visitor.user ORDER BY visitor.edition desc, social desc, visitor.id desc' in /home/indiamart/public_html/serve-biztradeshows-com/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryExce in /home/indiamart/public_html/serve-biztradeshows-com/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 44
```

Comment: i have found the solution and updated in  stackoverflow