# equivalent of nested if statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need a table that calculates percentage changes between columns of another table (current value - previous value) / previous value

if a value goes from 0 to anything the result should be 1, otherwise it would cause a division by 0 error.
if the current value is also 0, return 0. otherwise calculate the percentage change

how do I replicate this if block in sql?

```
if previous value == 0
    if current value == 0
        return 0
    return 1
return (current value - previous value) / previous value
```

Comment: you mean within a SELECT statement to choose the output of a particular column? Or as control flow logic in a stored procedure?

Comment: @ADyson in a select statement

Comment: Check out CASE then

Comment: Example of a nested CASE  in a SELECT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11618798/5947043

Answer (score 0):

If you want to nest the `if` statements in an `select` you can do it like this:

```
if(condition1, if(condition2, inner_true, inner_false), outer_false)
```

I don't necessarily claim that's the best solution to your problem compared to other ways to structure the query overall, but it does nest the if statements, as you requested.

If I understand what you meant by your non-select example, I think that would be for your case

```
select if(previous_value=0, if(current_value=0,0,1), (current_value-previous_value) / previous_value)
```