# SQL CASE STATEMENT IN A CASE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, case-statement

How do I make a case statement inside another case statement.  I need to find when condition1 = 77, then column value = y only if the y value is equal to 3. otherwise the value should be condition3

I tried coding it like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN confition1 LIKE '77' 
        THEN condition2 
CASE 
    WHEN condition2 LIKE '3' 
        THEN condition2 
ELSE condition3 
ELSE condition3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested CASE statements in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618730/nested-case-statements-in-mysql)

Comment: `case` _expression_ ... (The <case-statement> tag says "A case statement allows sequences of SQL statements to be selected for execution based on search or comparison criteria, and is typically used in stored procedures. **Do not use this tag**, use [switch-statement] instead.")

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @test INT = 2
DECLARE @test2 INT = 3

SELECT CASE 
    WHEN @test = 1 THEN 'One'
    WHEN @test = 2 THEN (CASE 
        WHEN @test2 = 2 THEN 'Two'
        ELSE 'Not Two' END)
    ELSE 'Unknown' END
```

Comment: This is a single case statement, not a case within another case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the following code will work

```
case when confition1 like '77' and condition2 LIKE '3' then condition2 
else condition3 end
```